# Extraer numeros sin repetir de una lista en 3 listas más pequeñas

Tags: python, python-3.7

Hola estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Python y estoy utilizando Sample de Random para Extraer 15 numeros de una lista de 90 ya que este me permite extraer 15 sin que se repita ninguno. Hasta ahi perfecto pero necesito realizar 2 extraciones mas de 15 numeros de la misma lista de 90 sin que ninguno de los que obtuve en la primera extraccion este en la lista2 y lo mismo para la lista3

Este es mi codigo hasta el momento-

```
from itertools import combinations as com 
from random import * 
    
#entrega un rango del 1 al 90 
list90=range(1,91) 

#extrae 15 numeros aleatoriamente del rango de 90 
list_15_1 =sample(list90,15) # primeros 15
list_15_2 =sample(list90,15) # segundos 15 diferente a los de **list_15_1** 
list_15_3 =sample(list90,15) # segundos 15 diferente a los de **list_15_1 y list_15_2**
```

Como puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: sería mejor que hicieras tu propia implementación de la función `sample` usando `choice`

Comment: Es lo unico que se te ocurre para aportarme ?

Comment: mmm... pues, aparte de eso puedes convertir la lista en sets e ir restando los elementos que ya usaste y pasarle al siguiente `sample` el set con los elementos actualizados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `random.shuffle(#lista)` que desordena aleatoriamente el orden de la lista, es `inplace` por lo que no es necesario asignar a un nuevo valor.

```py
import random
list90=list(range(1,91))

random.shuffle(list90)
# %%
list_15_1=list90[:15]
list_15_2=list90[15:30]
list_15_3=list90[30:45]
```

Se puede entender con la analogía de "barajar cartas" y repartir.

Comment: En lo posible trata de evitar convertir un rango en una lista. Pues cargas todos los numeros intermedios en memoria. Además, usando un pedazo de mi solución, la tuya puede generalizarse a n casos. Por lo demás no veo ningún problema c:

Comment: @DanteS. Podrías referenciar cómo convertir `range()` a `list` afecta negativamente, ¿Cómo verifico lo que mencionas de 'números intermedios en memoria'? He probado sin `list(...)` y el método `random.shuffle(...)` lanza error.

Comment: En una parte de [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#range.step) menciona que solo necesita guardar en memoria los valores para start, stop y step y el resto los va calculando, propiedad que una lista NO tiene. Igual decía que no lo hagas dentro de lo posible, y en este escenario no es posible.

Comment: Muchas gracias @alfredo creo que voy por esta opción porque es la mas corta y legible.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener 45 números y dividir la lista en 3 partes iguales. De esa manera tendrás elementos diferentes en 3 listas.

```
import random

def sample(iterable, num, parts):
    #tomo num*parts elementos aleatorios sin repetir del iterable. En tu caso sería 15*3 = 45
    iterable = random.sample(iterable, k=num*parts)

    # recorremos un rango que va de 0 al largo del iterable con saltos de num. En tu ejemplo esto sería 0, 15, 30
    for i in range(0, len(iterable), num):
        # devolvemos cada parte de la lista
        yield iterable[i:i+num]

# sample devuelve un objeto generador, por lo que se para poder visualizarlo lo transformo en lista.
print(list(sample(range(1, 91), 15, 3)))
```

Lo que produce:

```
[[41, 17, 90, 88, 26, 59, 4, 23, 27, 32, 67, 45, 14, 78, 82], [5, 35, 84, 68, 31, 36, 63, 66, 25, 65, 50, 37, 54, 44, 61], [62, 79, 20, 80, 70, 53, 22, 15, 51, 72, 55, 60, 18, 57, 7]]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Es una buena solución al igual que las otras que me ofrecen. Analizaré cual es la mejor opción al probarlo.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

list90 = pd.Series(range(1,91))

list_15_1 = list90.sample(15)

list_15_2 = list90[~list90.isin(list_15_1)].sample(15)

list_15_3 = list90[~list90.isin(pd.concat([list_15_1, list_15_2]))].sample(15)
```

Usando `pd.Series` conviertes la lista de números que creas en un vector de datos al que puedes aplicarle todas las funciones de Pandas correspondientes.

El método `sample` te permite obtener valores aleatorios del vector de datos.

Usando `[]` puedes filtrar los valores de un vector o de un `dataframe`. El método `isin` te permite identificar aquellos valores del vector de datos que se encuentran en otro vector o en un lista, agregado a eso. Con `~` puedes invertir el filtro.

Por ultimo `pd.concat` te permite pegar vectores de datos.

Todo es mejor con pandas.

Comment: totalmente innecesario pandas :/

Comment: Podrías explicar por que este código funciona y por que con Pandas es mejor por favor? Eso aumentará la calidad de tu respuesta y ayudará al aprendizaje del OP.

Comment: @Christian oí que pandas es más rapido por que tiene muchos bucles implementados en C. Si esto es cierto, esta solución también es valida.

Comment: Por cierto, tu solución puede ponerse en un bucle for y complejizarse un poco para expandirla a N casos.

Comment: @DanteS. pues sip pero usa otros módulos como numpy, y tener que importar todo eso para un simple `sample`  no  lo veo muy conveniente. Además que el OP usa `random` y tendrá sus motivos (como por ejemplo aprender de la librería).

Comment: @DanteS. bueno pues en mi experiencia Pandas siempre me ha facilitado el trabajo, no necesariamente por la rapidez de sus procesos sino por la facilidad a la hora de entender el código

Comment: @Christian tiene sentido

Comment: @DanielMendoza Ya veo. Bueno, eso también es un buen motivo. Sin embargo, concuerdo con Christian con que la propuesta puede ser algo overkill y (si la llevamos a n casos) compleja. Aun así, buena solución alternativa!

Comment: Estaría bueno una explicar lo que hace cada linea para aquellos que no conocen pandas.

Comment: Excelente. Creo que Pandas me puede ayudar. !! Muchas gracias por su tiempo a todos los q aportaron